# Altering nested messages helper from div to unordered list

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, helper, nested

I am using a helper method from ryan bates railscasts on [ancestry](http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry) to display nested messages(code below works perfectly).

```
def nested_messages(messages)
  messages.map do |message, sub_messages|
    render(message) + content_tag(:div, nested_messages(sub_messages), :class => "nested_messages")
  end.join.html_safe
end
```

The above bit of code nests the individual divs in a tree like structure. 
**I would like to make this into an unordered list, so what i have done is this:**

```
def nested_messages(messages)
    messages.map do |message, sub_messages|
        content_tag(:ul, :class => "") do
            render(message)
            content_tag(:li, :class => "nested_messages") do
                nested_messages(sub_messages)
            end
        end
    end.join.html_safe
end
```

The generated html looks fine, however the list items contain no values. Am i doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**

I would like the generated html to look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Main Message</li>  <!-- first message -->
    <li>
        <b>Message 1</b>
        <ul>
            <li>Message 1 subchild 1</li>
            <li>Message 1 subchild 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have changed it to this and it works, thanks to Dave:

```
def nested_messages(messages)
    messages.map do |message, sub_messages|
        #render(message) + content_tag(:div, sub_messages, :class => "nested_messages")
        content_tag(:ul, :class => "") do
            content_tag(:li, :class => "nested_messages") do
                render(message) + nested_messages(sub_messages)
            end
        end
    end.join.html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a `ul` tag, then render the message. If you do that, what will your HTML look like?

Things inside a `ul` should be in a nested `li`: you just render the message.

You need to put it in an `li` tag so the unordered list has valid content.